# When Cold Pitching is Too Successful

Tags: project-management, clients, writing

Last week I sent out cold pitching email to a few websites with three article ideas.

In the past, I've sent out tens of emails and only received one or two responses. This time, I sent out six emails and three responded. Two of the blogs wanted the same article idea.

I'd love to write for all three, though I don't have time to work on all three in a reasonable time frame. At the very least, I'd like to keep them as potential future clients.

Also, I'm not sure how to go about writing the same idea for two blogs without it being a duplicate or a totally different article than they agreed to.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably handled this already. But anyhow:

Simply pick your favorite site and go ahead with them. Try to back out of the others gracefully. If you didn't make any promises (say you just asked if they're interested), this shouldn't be too hard. Tell them demand is higher than expected, and someone else beat them to it. Make a replacement offer, like writing on a different topic or at a later time.

Comment: Thanks, @primateer! Your suggestion could definitely work if this ever happens again. I handled it slightly differently, which thankfully also worked out. I wrote about the same topic from a slightly different angle for the first two blogs, which took less time than two totally different articles because I used the same research for both. It was a bit challenging, but doable. And, the third one I simply gave them the frame I could manage, which they were fine with.